# Values not refreshing in UI after persisting by JPA, cache related

Tags: caching, jpa

I am developing an ecommerce java eneterprise applciation with JSF and JPA.
When I add items in the basket I can see them added in the database but not shown is the list of basket items which is taken from the database. At the second access I see the updated valuse. It seems that it is caching the values.

I would like to refresh the values constantly without caching. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

You can clear cache when adding something in basket or  you can adjust to not chace the entity which is responsible for basket .

if you use EclipseLink ;

1- You can use this anotation for basket entity

```
 @Cache(alwaysRefresh=true)
```

2- or you can refresh all cache with

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
```

but if you don't use eclipseLink , i think there are same solutions on your platform

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all!
I have found a solution: I have set Shared cache mode to None in the persistence.xml